# Rails methods in model not accessible in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have been fighting a annoying thing all day.

I have a model class which connects to another with has_many connection.  It works ok, but when I try to access non db methods from the class I get an error that the model does not contain the method.  I have put the method into attr_accessible so I would think it should be accessible.

Here is the model for the first class:

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name,  :presence => true,
                    :length   => { :maximum => 100 }

  attr_accessible :ingredient_recipes_attributes

  has_many :ingredient_recipes, :foreign_key => "recipe_id"
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_recipes

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_recipes, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

and the second model:

```
class IngredientRecipe < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :ingrNameFromUser

  set_primary_key :ingredient_id, :recipe_id

  attr_accessible :ingrNameFromUser, :readable_qty, :ingredient_description

  belongs_to :recipe, :foreign_key => "recipe_id"
  belongs_to :ingredient, :foreign_key => "ingredient_id"
  # belongs_to :ndbfoodde, :foreign_key => "ingredient_id"kki"

  delegate :description, :to => :ingredient, :prefix => "ingredient", :allow_nil => true

  def readable_qty
    qty.to_s + " gr."
  end

  def readable_qty=(qty)
    self.qty = qty.to_f + 2
  end
end
```

when I try to access the readable_qty through the view like this:

```
 <% f.fields_for :ingredient_recipes do |rif| %>        
          <td>            

              <%= rif.autocomplete_field :ingrNameFromUser, recipes_autocomplete_ingredient_description_path, :value => @recipe.ingredient_recipes[i].ingrNameFromUser, :width=>1000, :size=>60 %>
          </td>  

          <td>         
          <%= rif.text_field :readable_qty %>
        </td>
```

I get an error:

```
undefined method `readable_qty' for #<IngredientRecipe:0x00000103322068>

Extracted source (around line #59):

56:           </td>  
57:           
58:           <td>         
59:           <%= rif.text_field :readable_qty %>
60:         </td>
61:         
62:         <td>
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it possible that the `def readable_qty` is after a `private` or `protected` call in the class, thus making the method private/protected?

Answer (score 0):

At first glance, I'd say that given `readable_qty` is a virtual attribute (i.e. it isn't in the database and has instance methods as setters and getters, you should remove it from the `attr_accessible` list. This list defines which attributes stored in the database can be updated by mass assignment.

But `readable_qty` isn't a database field, so it doesn't belong in the list.

Comment: I removed readable_qty from attr_accessible but I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Try implementing it like here http://asciicasts.com/episodes/167-more-on-virtual-attributes

Comment: The method is implemented correctly on the model an should be accessible in the view

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
attr_accessor :readable_qty
```

to IngredientRecipe.

Comment: I added the line but I'm still getting the error that it is undefined: undefined method `readable_qty'

Answer (score 0):

If you're running the server in production mode and you've made this change to the model, then the model will not be reloaded automatically and the new method would not be available. You must restart the server for it to take effect.